# Migrate a Non Wordpress database to wordpress

Tags: database, migration

I have a MySQL database with 71 tables. It houses news, galleries, slideshow data, page content, products, customers, shipping, discount codes, ( basically a full store build on a PHP shop).

I want to migrate over to WP. I'm new to wordpress, how easy/difficult will this be? I can do a SQL dump of the database easily. But how easy will it be to map the tables, structure and data to wordpress tables? Is there any plugin that can help?

Comment: I would say you're most likely looking at hiring someone to do some custom work for you. You *might* be able to get away with using something like [`curl`](https://curl.haxx.se/) or [`wget`](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) to spider your site (ie, download it to a directory of HTML files) and then use a plugin like [HTML Import 2](https://wordpress.org/plugins/import-html-pages/), though that will depend on how complex your pages are and how much of your content maps nicely to WordPress's built-in post types.

Comment: Thanks for responding, however, the site is being completely reworked and redesigned so I don't want to download any of the HTML. I just need the data in the database to migrate to wordpress in the correct format. IE, Blog posts, news items, galleries. I built the original site (php/MySQL) and it uses a custom CMS. So I have all the php files associated with the site. Does anyone know of a plugin, or a tutorial to follow that would help me out?

Comment: This is one of the most tricky and maybe time consuming tasks in the entire web developing process. You could copy a few lines of your database/table structure so we can investigate, but still it won't be easy.

Comment: even trying to post ONE table structure isn't allowed on here because of the character count. That is frustrating for sure.

Comment: downvoted and close voted as from the comments it is obvious there are huge amounts of details that are missing from the question. right now you are wasting everybody time in guessing what is it you want to convert. Question should include ALL the relevant details and not make people interrogate you like we are in  a basement of some three letters secret service.

Comment: Mark,
That's some pretty rude comments you made and in my opinion completely uncalled for. I tried to include as much detail as I could. What other "details" do you think were missing?

Comment: Mark,
That's some pretty rude comments you made and in my opinion completely uncalled for. I tried to include as much detail as I could. What other "details" do you think were missing?
I explained exactly what the database content holds, how many tables it has and what platform it was built on. I said what shopping cart was used, how many products, the nature of the business. What's information is missing that put you in a basement with the secret service? If you don't have anything to contribute move on. I wasn't aware you needed more details to be a decent human being.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not really and easy process.  It's not about just having a table.  The tables in WordPress will have different names, fields, and relationships than the cms you're pulling your table from.  That's just for the content.  Then to mirror appearance will definitely be starting over all the same.

It would likely be a much easier process to create a new wordpress install with a clean install and manually set up new pages with the old content.

Without knowing more about your current CMS or how much content you have I'd strongly suggest you go this route.  Sorry for the bad news, but good luck and you'll love wordpress.

UPDATE BASED ON COMMENT

While by no means an endorsement, you may want to check out wpallimport.  It will let you set up imports based on CSV files and let you import them into any post type.  It doesn't have that steep of a learning curve, but it will even let you attach photos to the posts to update!

Comment: To manually enter the pages is not an issue. But, there are over 200 products and each product has more than 1 sku. There are over 200 customers, and over 2000 orders. That can't be manually added. I'd be here forever!

The pages themselves wouldn't be difficult but it's a beauty / hair care site, the galleries, in the news, press is just daunting to add by hand for 5 brands.

Comment: does the system you're using have an export function for products?  Depending on what you plan on moving into there are ways to import products from csv.  That would be MUCH faster, but again, I don't know what you're moving from or now by "product" if you're actually planning on selling online or of its just a catalog.

Comment: It's a cartweaver shop running on a CMS built by a PHP programmer. It's a basic set up to allow end users to post blog articles (his own blog) and add pages (basic pages) to the site. Thing is the site has 5 different hair care brands, each with their own products, galleries, news, press items, and videos. It gets complicated. 

Yes, they are selling online. I can do a complete SQL dump of the database to a cvs without issue. I already have that.

Comment: see update to question, may be just what you're looking for,.

Comment: Thank you rudtek, I will look at that. I appreciate your helpful comments and your willingness to reach out and make a difference. Mark could learn something from you.

Comment: rudtek, I had to come back to reply to you and say thank you. I checked into wpallimport and tried the demo. It made everything perfect! Literally got everything exported from my original DB into the woo commerce set up in minutes. Well worth the cost of the plug in. This saved me days and days of work. Thank you for your suggestion it is perfect!

Comment: Nice!  I'm glad to hear it.  Not sure if you can as it's on hold but would you mind trying to mark as answererd?  It's the check mark to the left of the answer

Comment: I would, but don't see a way to do that. Might be because its on hold.