# How to migrate a website based on a custom database to wordpress?

Tags: database

My question is similar to [that one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/262702/migrate-a-non-wordpress-database-to-wordpress) which was closed for being too broad, so I'll try to be clearer.

**What I have**: a sqlite database (single table) containing over 50'000 posts (with fields like author, content, date, etc.). It stems from scraping a huge static, html-only website.

**What I want to achieve**: displaying those posts in a standard WP installation.

**My approach**: I would

1. Initialize an empty WordPress website
2. Write a script that reads a post from the original DB and writes it into the corresponding fields of the WP database (ID -> ID, author -> author, date -> date, ...)
3. Run the WordPress engine engine and expect the posts to appear

**My question**: is this approach likely to succeed, or should I avoid this futile work and consider other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any reason for this not to work. I have done similar transfers few times, and if you transfer all data correctly, and if posts in the wp_posts are well formed, with all data present (status, type...), it will work.

The tricky part might be the data that can't fit into wp_posts, and it should go into wp_postmeta, you need to take care of proper post ids. Also, make sure to use correct format for date field, make sure to have both post_date and post_date_gmt filled, guid (some unique string for each post, WP uses URL by default), and make sure author ID's are correct.

Comment: I'd personally not work on the raw tables, but use WP's `wp_insert_post` and friends, so WP will take care of everything else, but it should work just as fine working directly on the tables.

Comment: If you have a lot of posts, it is better to use direct SQL approach, it will be much faster. But, nothing wrong with wp_insert_post for something like this.